# Android Relative Layout Bottom to Bottom Side By Side Problem

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to show two text views in a side by side layout. In addition I have to do this in 3 columns but I have to put them side by side. I did it one under the other but I couldn't side by side them all together unfortunately. What I want to do is: I want to bring these together, but it must be in a layout. I would really appreciate it if you show me how I can do this in the relative layout.

**Screenshot**

[image]

```
  <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="left"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/calismalartext"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:lines="1"
                                android:padding="2dp"
                                android:text="Çalışmalar"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="13sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/prof_Works"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/calismalartext"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:lines="1"
                                android:padding="1dp"
                                android:text=""
                                android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_orange"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="13sp" />
                          </RelativeLayout>


                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/takiptext"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:lines="1"
                                android:padding="2dp"
                                android:text="Takip"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="13sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                            
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/prof_Follows"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_orange"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/takiptext"
                                android:lines="1"
                                android:padding="1dp"
                                android:text=""
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="13sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>


                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/takipcitext"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         
                                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:lines="1"
                                android:padding="2dp"
                                android:text="Takipçi"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="13sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/prof_Followers"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_orange"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:lines="1"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/takipcitext"
                                android:padding="1dp"
                                android:text=""
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="13sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Wrap them in a horizontal linear layout?

Comment: Or use a constraint layout, using relative layout is no longer recommended at this point in time as its not efficient or there a no performance gains.